# What preposition would you use?

Tags: prepositions

Do you say I´ll arrive **in** the first week of July? or **on** the first week of July?

Answer (score 5):

> You arrive ***in*** the first week of July...***on*** a jet plane.
>
> You arrive ***on*** July 4th...***in*** a jet plane.

For month/week, use the preposition "in." For specific dates, use the preposition "on."

Comment: Why use "on a jet plane" in the 1st sentence and "in a jet plane" to the 2nd?

Answer (score 3):

It is also acceptable to use no preposition whatsoever:

> I'll arrive the first week of July

This is also acceptable with specific days

> I'll arrive July 5th

This does not work with specific years.

> I'll arrive in 2014. (only 'in' works)

However you can say

> I'll arrive next year. ('in' would be incorrect here.)

Answer (score 2):

Neither. I would say:

> I´ll arrive **during** the first week of July.

Answer (score 2):

The preposition 'in' is used with parts of the day, months, years, seasons etc.
Whereas 'on' is used with days and dates.

So for the question asked, '**I'll arrive in the first week of July.**' is the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**'IN'** is used with:

- parts of the day (in the morning, in the afternoon, in the evening; note the exception: *at* night)
- longer periods of time - weeks (in the 1st week of July), months (in July, in July 1969), years (in 2014), centuries (in the 15th c.)
- seasons (in winter)

**'ON'** is used with:

- weekdays (on Monday)
- dates where the day of the month or another sequential number is given (on the 5th, on July 4th, on day 12)
- events - both astronomical (on an eclipse) and human (on my birthday, on Independence Day)
- parts of the day, when they are described somehow (on Monday morning, on some afternoons, on a cold winter night)
- weeks, when more than one occurred during a set amount of time - typically followed by a/an (on a cold week in July)
- weekends in AmE (on the weekend)

**'AT'** is used with:

- "at night" (an exception)
- exact times (at 5 o'clock)
- longer-than-one-day holidays (at Christmas, but on Christmas Eve)
- weekends in BrE (at the weekend)

**nothing** is used with:

- next/last/etc followed by any of the above (weekday,week,...,year,century), when used without the 'the' article ('I arrived last week', 'I'll be there next Tuesday', etc.)

---

In your case, since you're using "first week", you need "in": **"I'll arrive in the first week of July."**'

Answer (score -2):

I would either use "on" - or NO preposition, which I think is more natural.